# Customizing select for dataviewgrid

Tags: c#, .net, sql

I have a table "events" that has the following fields: `id`, `id_client`, `data_field`.

The id_client makes a reference to a table "clients" that has the following fields: `id`, `name`.

I would like to display in my dataviewgrid the data_field and the name of my id_client (from the "clients" table).

How can I make a sql statement so that I may fill my dataview with the apropriate data?

(Note that my data_field is actually a lot of fields, but I only named data_field for convenience in explaining.)

Answer (score 1):

You mean like this?:

```
SELECT events.id, clients.name, events.data_field
FROM events
  INNER JOIN clients ON events.id_client = clients.id
```

This will retrieve all events with their `id`, the `name` of the associated client, and the `data_field`.

(Additionally, if for a given `events` record there isn't always a corresponding `clients` record then you can replace `INNER JOIN` with `LEFT OUTER JOIN`.)